# Help with MPICH2 installation on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt, linux

I'm trying to install MPICH2 on a ubuntu server installation (7.04 fiesty fawn).  This is for a Beowulf cluster.

I have so far been unable to install it for two reasons.

1) under the root account:

```
apt-get install mpich2
```

yields the following:

```
Package mpich2 is not available, but is referred to by another package 
E: Package mpich2 has no installation candidate
```

2) When installing from a tar ball using the following instructions from cd /mirror

```
mkidr mpich2
tar xvf mpich2_1.3.1.orig.tar.gz (creates directory /mirror/mpich2-1.3.1)
cd mpich2­-1.3.1
./configure --­prefix=/mirror/mpich2
make
sudo make install
```

everything goes fine until make, where i am informed:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

there is a small indent on my desk shaped curiously like my forehead.  What do you suppose I do to get this bloody software installed?

Comment: Re. your second question: What is the last thing on your screen after running `./configure`?  I bet everything did not go fine (if everything went fine you would have a Makefile.  If you have no Makefile configure probably failed to complete successfully.)

Comment: I realized that using such an old version is why the repositories don't have mpich2 anymore.  will try again with newer versions, both with apt-get and the tarball.

Comment: ah, I didn't even notice you were on Feisty -- yeah, that's a bit ancient :-)

Answer (score 0):

Re: (1) -

1. Are you sure you have the appropriate apt repository configured? (I'm not sure where this lives, but [here is a list of the repos for Natty](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Natty#Add_Extra_Repositories)).
2. Have you done `apt-get update` to make sure your package lists are up to date?
3. Have you tried `apt-cache search MPI` in case the package was renamed?

Re: (2) -
See comment above.